# jQuery - issue with call changed id elements

Tags: jquery, html

I'm trying to create some script with jQuery and PHP

I have multiple elements generated from database and display in same div with different name tag, when i click on some div I start jQuery call and function to post value from name true PHP, and later I need change id tag with elements by name.

HTML

```
<li class="todo-item">
  <div class="checkbox checkbox-success" ?> 
    <input type="checkbox" id="zadatak" name="<?php echo $row2["id"];?>" 
    <?php if ($row2['status'] == '1'){ echo "checked"; }?>>
      <label for="checkbox02">
        <?php echo $row2["zadatak"]; ?>
      </label>
  </div>
</li>
```

jQuery

```
<script>
  //ajax call_user_func
  $(document).ready(function() {    
    var x_timer;    
    $("#zadatak").bind('click keyup', function (e){
      clearTimeout(x_timer);
      var id = $(this).attr('name');
      x_timer = setTimeout(function(){
        ajax_zadatak(id);
      }, 100);
    });

    $("#zadatak2").bind('click keyup', function (e){
      clearTimeout(x_timer);
      var id2 = $(this).attr('name');
      x_timer = setTimeout(function(){
        ajax_zadatak2(id2);
      }, 100);
      console.log("k1");
    });

    function ajax_zadatak(id){
      $.post('ajax/zadaci.php',{'id':id}, function(data) {
        $("#zadatak-poruka").html(data);
      });
    }

    function ajax_zadatak2(id2){
      $.post('ajax/zadaci2.php',{'id2':id2}, function(data) {
        $("#zadatak-poruka").html(data);
      });
    }    
  });
</script>
```

PHP

In bouth PHP files I have jQuery code for change ID whit elementName tag

zadaci.php

```
<script>
  $(\'[name="'.$id.'"]\').attr("id","zadatak2");
</script>
```

zadaci2.php

```
<script>
  $(\'[name="'.$id.'"]\').attr("id","zadatak");
</script>
```

And problem start when I change in ajax PHP code ID like 
first I have `ID = zadatak` and I change it to `ID = zadatak2` and when I try click zadtak2 my jQuery call fith #zadatak2 not work.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I change my JQ code.

```
<script>
//ajax call_user_func
$(document).ready(function() {

var x_timer;

$('.todo-item [type="checkbox"]').bind('click keyup', function (e) {

clearTimeout(x_timer);
var id = $(this).attr('name');
if (this.checked)
x_timer = setTimeout(function () {ajax_zadatak(id)}, 100);
else
x_timer = setTimeout(function () {ajax_zadatak2(id)}, 100);
}); 


function ajax_zadatak(id){
$.post('ajax/zadaci.php',{'id':id}, function(data) {
$("#zadatak-poruka").html(data);
});
}

function ajax_zadatak2(id){
$.post('ajax/zadaci2.php',{'id':id}, function(data) {
$("#zadatak-poruka").html(data);
});
}

});
</script>
```